# Why is phenol soluble in sodium carbonate but not in sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: solubility

The original question was basically to predict which of sodium carbonate or sodium bicarbonate can be used to distinguish between phenol and benzene.

I was sure that phenol neither reacts nor dissolves in $\ce{NaHCO3}$ but I was not sure about the $\ce{Na2CO3}$.  By searching on Google I found that phenol ***is*** soluble in sodium carbonate. I am curious to know why this is, even though phenol doesn't liberate $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is less basic than $\ce{Na2CO3}$. Phenol is weakly acidic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The liberation of $\ce{CO2}$ from $\ce{Na2CO3}$ requires two protonation steps.

$$\begin{align}
\ce{CO3^2- + HA &<=> HCO3- + A-}\\
\ce{HCO3- + HA &<=> CO2 ^ + H2O + A-}
\end{align}$$

Neglecting the concentrations, the position of these equilibria will depend on the acid strength of $\ce{HA}$. If $\ce{HA}$ is a stronger acid than $\ce{HCO3-}$, for example, the first equilibrium will favour the products.

This is the case for phenol, which has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $9.95$, whereas $\ce{HCO3-}$ has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $10.32$. Therefore, as long as you don't have too much phenol, it will exist in the soluble phenolate form:

$$\ce{PhOH + CO3^2- <=>> PhO- + HCO3-}$$

The solubility of phenol does not *necessitate* that it releases carbon dioxide.

---

Now, the second protonation. If you want to quantitatively determine whether $\ce{CO2}$ will actually be liberated, you need more data than the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values, since quite a significant amount of $\ce{CO2}$ can exist in the aqueous form. However, one thing is certain: if you want to produce $\ce{CO2 (g)}$ you first have to protonate $\ce{HCO3-}$ to form $\ce{H2CO3}$ (which dissociates to give $\ce{CO2 (aq)}$).

This is not possible with phenol, since $\ce{H2CO3}$ has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $6.3$ (even after correcting for dissolved $\ce{CO2}$).